# How to refer to *one side* of headphones?

Tags: word-request, singular-vs-plural, image-identification

How to refer to *one side* of headphones? 
The word "**headphones**" is in only plural form, referring to two main components (speakers?) that are put in two ears.

Now my question is how to refer to each side of the headphones **separately**? (It is relevant for example in case that one of the sides doesn't work anymore.)

I know that I can say simply and generally "*one side*" doesn't work, but in my native language I can say "headphone" in singular form, then I'm looking for the accurate term for each one of them as a singular)

In addition, there is "headphones" that come/s just for one side only (see second picture), normally for people / host in TV shows, or security-men / policemen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update: I've look in Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries and only the plural form exist there. Anyway in Wiktionary there are TWO forms: Headphone and Headphones. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/headphone

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to a Speaker. i.e, "The **left speaker** on my headphones are broken, do you think it could be repaired?" Here's a definition from **Dictionary**;

> speaker - Computer Definition. A **device** containing a transducer that converts electrical signals (electric current) into **sound waves** (acoustic energy) for the **production of sound**.

Comment: Thank you, then what is it (one speaker headphones) called? (see the picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXPbWm.jpg)

Comment: I believe they are called earpieces? Security usually have / wear earpieces to events to communicate with each other neatly whilst having hearing in the other ear also.

Comment: For in-ear headphones, it's an earbud.

Comment: Both works, I assumed this would be said in an informal setting. Use the above if you're trying to be formal.